# Remove astuetz Pager Sliding Tab Strip shadow

Tags: android

I am using Android PagerSlidingTabStrip of astuetz.
[Github link](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

My problem is that:
I don't know how to remove the shadow between the tab strip and the action bar.
I had already removed any shadow of overlay from the action bar to the layout.

Here is an image to express my problem:
[image: You can see a narrow divider between the action bar and the tab strip which i want to be in the same color of action bar.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I need to use Toolbar and not ActionBar.

Comment: That's the correct solution. Look at Joris73's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add windowContentOverlay in your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

If your api is >= v21/lollipop (material design) windowContentOverlay is "deprecated" then add:

```
<item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
```

Change the dp value for remove this shadow.

Ps: Maybe you should be adding **android: elevation** on elements of your layout.

Answer (score 0):

the one that is producing the shadow is the actionbar modify the style:

@null

in lollypop you need to call:
actionbar.setElevation(0);

Comment: <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

Comment: Please modify your answer, avoid answers on comment.